# Turn off Emmet suggestion in Vue CSS part (VS Code)

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, emmet

I am programing with **Vue** in VS Code, I want to **enabled** Emmet in <template> part of .vue file, but want to turn **disable** emmet in <style> part because of this annoying suggestion that can be seen it the following image:

EDIT: I am using Volar (v0.35.0), I just tried Vetur and the problem does not exist there

[image: Problem Image]

Comment: Try creating an issue on GitHub of Volar/Vetur whatever you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was fixed in v0.35.2, as can be seen [HERE](https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/1358).

To check which version you have go to the extensions tab in VS Code and choose Volar. You can see the version number next to the extension name. If you want to upgrade you can press the arrow next to "uninstall" and press "Install Another Version".

[image]